# Are there problems with CSS drawing and Zepto / Phonegap?

Tags: css, cordova, drawing, zepto

I'm trying to draw a circle with CSS, and it's not rendering. Here's my code:

```
<div id="circle" height="65" width="65" position="absolute"></div>
```

and in the CSS file:

```
#circle {
  background:blue;
  width:65;
  height:65;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

Am I making a mistake with this, or is there a problem with CSS and Zepto or Phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost `px`

```
#circle {
  background:blue;
  width:65px;
  height:65px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

test in:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kjy5y/